# requests not returning full html from a page

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to get full HTML off of a webpage with Python for a little project I am doing. The HTML I get from printing the HTML is different from what I see on Chrome. Urllib does the same thing, I have also tried using selenium webdriver but the info on the webpage is always updating and I don't want to have it constantly opening Chrome.

Comment: if the web page is dynamically updating, it's using JS, which vanilla requests doesn't support.

Comment: If the data on the page is always updating it's because the HTML is generated by a script. You have no choice but use something like selenium that could parse that, but selenium doesn't have to open Chrome to do its job. I suggest you ask another question about that (after doing some research of your own first)

Comment: requests can only correctly fetch server side  created HTML. if it is created by javascripts and you really need the entire html, then requests is not your solution. You had to run a real browser executing javascript and having a real DOM. you might look at `selenium`, `pyqt` with `webkit` or `cefpython` (embedded chrome)